# Tablesorter addParser returning s is undefined

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Working with Tablesorter and I am trying to write a date parser for dd/mm/yy format.   It looks like the table gets to the parser, but my string (s) is always coming up undefined.

Any ideas?  I am kinda new to tablesorter

Here's my code:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser(
{
  id: "my_date_sorter",
  is: function(s) {
      return false;
      // return /\d{1,4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/;
  },
  format: function(s) 
  {
      console.log(s);
      if (s)
      {
        console.log("In myDateSorter s = " + s);
        s = s.replace(/\-/g,"/");
        s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{2})/, "$3/$2/$1");
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(s).getTime());
      }
      else
      {
        return;
      }
  },
  type: "numeric"
});  // end addParser

$(document).ready(function() {
  $( '.tablesorter' ).each( function()
  {
    // Allow default sort key override by data-sort-key attr per table.
    var SortKey = $(this).attr('data-sort-key');
    if( SortKey == undefined )
    { 
      SortKey = 3; 
    }

    $(this).tablesorter (
    {
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      headers: 
      { 
        2: 
        {
          sorter:'my_date_sorter'
        },
        6: 
        {  // don't sort the image column
          sorter:false 
        } 
      }, 
      sortList: [ [ SortKey, 0 ] ],
      textExtraction: function (node) 
      {
        var strippedNodeText  = $(node).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "");
        if ( ( $(node).index() == 2 ) && ( strippedNodeText == 'tbd' ) )
        {
      //    $(node).parent().addClass('jsnamark');
        }            
        // return $(node).text();
      } // end textExtraction
    })
    .bind('sortEnd', function () 
    {
       $(this).append( $(this).find('.jsnamark') );
       $(this).trigger("update");
    });
  }); // end  $( '.tablesorter' ).each( function()
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with the textExtraction function being added as well.   For some reason, that was causing the parser not to work correctly.

Via the custom parser I was able to get the code working properly while still "throwing out" bad strings in my date column (such as "TBD") new code is below:

```
 /* my_date_sorter custom parser that will parse and sort the given column by mm/dd/yy format.
// anything that is not in that format will go to the bottom of the table (by default).
*/
$.tablesorter.addParser(
{
  id: "my_date_sorter",
  is: function(s) 
  {
      return false;  
  },
  format: function(s) 
  {
      if (s) 
      {
        var dateSplit = s.split('/');
        if (3 !== dateSplit.length)
        {
          return 0;
        }
        return new Date(dateSplit[2], dateSplit[1], dateSplit[0], 1);
      }
      else
      {
        return 0;
      }
  },
  type: "numeric"
});  // end addParser

 $(document).ready(function() 
{
  $( '.tablesorter' ).each( function()
  {
    // Allow default sort key override by data-sort-key attr per table.
    var SortKey = $(this).attr('data-sort-key');
    if( SortKey == undefined )
    { 
      SortKey = 3; 
    }

    $(this).tablesorter (
    {
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      headers: 
      { 
        2: 
        {
          sorter: 'my_date_sorter'  // use custom parser
        },
        6: 
        {  // don't sort the image column
          sorter: false 
        } 
      }, 
      sortList: [ [ SortKey, 0 ] ]
    });
  }); // end  $( '.tablesorter' ).each( function()
});
```